# How do I get Windows to showup on my boot menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, menu

I'm sort of new to all this, and am not quite sure what I did.  I somehow managed to delete the boot menu from my computer, so when it starts it automatically goes into Ubuntu. I got the boot menu back using boot-repair, but now Windows 7 isn't showing up as an option in the menu.  Can anyone explain how to fix this and make it an option again?

UPDATE: I've been trying to figure out what I did wrong, and based on other things I read it looks like there's supposed to be a second boot partition for windows and that is what I accidentally deleted somehow. So now grub does not recognize that windows is there.  How do I fix that?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12073785/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12073797/

Comment: Usually one selects which OS to boot in the BIOS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you please post the contents of your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/default/grub` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and [edit] your answer and add the links to both pastes.  Additionally add the output of  `sudo parted --list` to your question as well and then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12073806/

Comment: There's the 3, it would only let me add 2 to the question, so the sudo parted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

In a Terminal, type `sudo update-grub`. Assuming GRUB can see the Windows disk/partition, it should add it to the menu.

Comment: I tried to update, but windows still isn't showing up.  Tried the first comment as well, but nothing.  But when I go into disks I can see the windows partition there, for some reason grub just isn't recognizing it I guess. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal type this:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda; sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This will install GRUB fresh on your hard drive, and update the current config file, ensuring a fresh configuration everywhere.